# How to adjust width of individual plotly funnel sections?

Tags: r, graph, formatting, plotly, r-plotly

I am building a stacked funnel graph with plotly with 5 variables. Towards the bottom of the graph, the rectangles becomes so narrow that it's hard to read the values of the data labels. I've tried adjusting the overall graph width itself `plot_ly(width = 1200, height = 800)` however that doesn't solve the issue. I would like to be able to have that type of flexibility for each step of the funnel. Is that possible?

EDIT: As an example, I took the stacked graph from here: https://plotly.com/r/funnel-charts/ and extended the data so they all go through the entire funnel. As you can see, for the last stages, it's hard to read. I would like to find a way to make it readable.

Code adapted from website above:

```
fig <- plot_ly(height = 1200, width = 800,
    type = "funnel",
    name = 'Montreal',
    y = c("Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent", "Finalized"),
    x = c(120, 60, 30, 20, 10, 5),
    textinfo = "value+percent initial") 
fig <- fig %>%
    add_trace(
        type = "funnel",
        name = 'Toronto',
        orientation = "h",
        y = c("Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent", "Finalized"),
        x = c(100, 60, 40, 30, 20, 10),
        textposition = "inside",
        textinfo = "value+percent previous") 
fig <- fig %>%
    add_trace(
        type = "funnel",
        name = 'Vancouver',
        orientation = "h",
        y = c("Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent", "Finalized"),
        x = c(90, 70, 50, 30, 10, 5),
        textposition = "outside",
        textinfo = "value+percent total") 
fig <- fig %>%
    layout(yaxis = list(categoryarray = c("Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent", "Finalized")))

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code that you used to generate your graph and the data that you're using? You can share the data using `dput()`.  It is very difficult to help without the code and data that you're using

Comment: @neuron Yes, sorry, I just added the code to my post.

Comment: @neuron Did the added code help at all?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a way to do this. Each step of the funnel gets smaller because the values in each step get smaller. If you were to change the values of the last step to something like 120,100, and 90 then the last step would be the same size as the first step. Outside of changing the overall width and height of the plot, I am not sure there is anything that can be done at this moment. Plotly also has the ability to zoom in which makes it easier to read those bottom values

Comment: Plotly has a lot of nice features and different types of plots however they lack tunability. A lot of posts on SO involving plotly typically involve a workaround because there aren't many ways to tune plots like you want to.

Comment: @neuron That's a bummer. Thanks for looking into this!